# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ".";

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, squirrel-sql

Thanks for any help with this.
I realise this would have been asked before but I am totally confused by this error. I didn't write the code, I just run the script, it used to work for me but stopped working for some reason.

I'm connected to Amazon Redshift using Squirrell. There isn't any connection issues from what I can gather as I'm able to run other queries, it just seems to be this particular query that won't work.

When I run it, I get the following error:

```html
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ".";
```

This is my code:

```js
SELECT 
'response = queue.send_message(MessageBody=''{"eventName": "reports", "user_id": "' 
+ h.userid + '",  "sales_date": "' 
+ To_char(Dateadd(d, -1, h.timestamp), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
+ '", "seller_id": ' + cc.id 
+ ',   "include_saleitems": "True", "saleitems_limit":}'')' 
FROM   historicsales h 
       INNER JOIN eng_retailer 
               ON h.discountid = eng_retailer.discountid 
       INNER JOIN crm_retailer 
               ON eng_retailer.id = crm_customerretailer.retailerid 
       INNER JOIN crm_customer cc 
               ON crm_customerretailer.customerid = cc.id 
WHERE  To_char(h.timeofsale.timestamp, 'MONYY') = :MONYY 
       AND cc.discountedsellers = 'd' 
       AND ( ( Date_part(dayofweek, h.timeofsale) = :dayofweek ) 
              OR ( Date_part(dayofweek, h.timeofsale) = 
                   Date_part(dayofweek, h.timeofsale) 
                   AND :dayofweek = 8 ) ) 
       AND cc.id = :customerid 
ORDER  BY cc.id, 
          h.timeofsale;
```

Comment: You have a table `crm_retailer` that you reference as `crm_customerretailer`